# Drools Decision Table - fails with compilation error - method is undefined

Tags: drools

Am trying to create a rule via Decision table :
[image]

Premium is a simple POJO :

```
public class Premium{

    private String coverType;
    private String generatedCriteria;
    private double loadFactor;

    // getters and setters 
    public void setLoadFactor(double loadFactor) {
        this.loadFactor = loadFactor;
    }   
}
```

On startup - get following error :

```
Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='Premium LF_9']
sample_business_rules/Rule_Premium_LF_9646103723.java (7:408) : 
The method setLoadFactor(double) is undefined for the type Rule_Premium_LF_9646103723
```

Note:

- 'RuleTable Premium LF' ( row 4 ) is merged across columns B , C and D
- '$premium:Premium' ( row 6 ) is merged across column B and C

Edit2 : Thanks to @Roddy - here is what I did to resolve this issue :
[image]

@roddy please provide add your comments as an answer , happy to accept it and once again thank you for helping me with numerous questions
( some more are on the way ! )

Comment: Where is `setLoadFactor` defined?

Comment: its defined in Premium , will edit the question and the image to reflect the same

Comment: edited the question with updated image of defined rules and setter details , thank you

Comment: Right, but you're not calling `$premium.setLoadFactor(...)` you're calling `setLoadFactor`. Are you not showing a modify block?

Comment: cool , what you say makes sense corrected it and it works , can you please add your response as an answer , will accept it