# drools - will all rules fire , if so what is the alternative or is this a bad use case / design the way I am using drools?

Tags: drools

This question is a followup to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273167/drools-decision-table-fails-with-compilation-error-method-is-undefined)

so my decision table rule looks like below :
[image]

Questions :
Below is just a short snapshot - I can have about 60 rows for Male and 60 for Female ( between ages of 20-81 )
then add to it the Type of Cover ( Deathonly , Income protection , Death + Income protection )
so the rows ( rules ) would thereby increase . ( 60 + 60 = 120 * 3 = 360 rules )

presently in java this has been implemented as a HashMap
( I often feel Maps lend themselves better that writing if / else - not sure everyone would agree )
since it is implemented as a map - simply extract load factor and age from appropriate map ( Death Map / Income protection Map / Death + Income protection Map )

However when this is done via drools I am assuming that all the rules will fire - which is kind of an overhead .

so whats the best approach ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate best approach is the following:

> If you need key value mapping - use java hash map, if you need rete algorithm - use drools.